# Matching colums and rows in a special condition

Tags: r, merge

```
output1 <- output1 <- structure(list(row = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 214L, 214L,214L), col = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 110L, 111L,111L), cell = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 27244L, 27245L, 27245L), xcoord = c(783750L, 783750L, 783750L, 783750L, 783750L, 783750L,783725L, 786075L, 786100L, 786100L), ycoord = c(187050L, 187050L,187050L, 187050L, 187050L, 187050L, 187025L, 181725L, 181725L,181725L), species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 1L,3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("abiealba", "alnuinca", "alnuviri", "betupend","betupube", "fagusilv", "larideci", "piceabie", "pinucemb", "pinusilv","popunigr", "poputrem", "salicapr", "sorbaucu"), class = "factor"),age = c(100L, 20L, 10L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 30L, 70L,30L), biomass = c(0.1015, 0.0152, 0.0127, 0.5391, 0.02, 0.1584,0.1019, 0.0114, 0.0115, 0.0114), stems = c(1L, 10L, 10L,20L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 15L, 2L, 10L), slowGrowth = c(0L, 0L, 0L,0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DBH = c(17.9273, 8.831, 8.2681,34.9717, 9.7366, 18.9254, 17.9523, 6.6486, 6.6793, 6.6486), height = c(14.0924, 8.0258, 7.625, 23.4468, 8.0478, 13.6345,14.1081, 3.6519, 3.6552, 3.6519), availableLight = c(0.0934,0.0807, 0.071, 0.4742, 0.0887, 0.101, 0.0985, 0.958, 0.9952,0.9624), light_rf = c(0.2619, 0.2067, 0.1708, 0.6971, 0.063,0.1049, 0.2896, 0.9768, 0.9972, 0.9793), LeafArea = c(5.4506,5.4506, 5.4506, 5.4506, 5.4506, 5.4506, 5.2884, 0.2307, 0.1732,0.1732), nitorgen_rf = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1328, 0, 0, 0, 0,0), droughtIndex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), moisture_rf = c(1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), degreeDay_rf = c(0.258, 0.258,0.258, 0.4726, 0.5144, 0.237, 0.258, 0.1125, 0.1125, 0.1125), foliageWght = c(0.0093, 0.0031, 0.0028, 0.0265, 0.0036,0.0023, 0.0094, 5e-04, 5e-04, 5e-04), twigWght = c(0.0537,0.0115, 0.0096, 0.0513, 0.0149, 0.0847, 0.0538, 0.0109, 0.011,0.0109), boleWght = c(0.0384, 6e-04, 3e-04, 0.4613, 0.0015,0.0713, 0.0387, 0, 0, 0), deadFoliage = c(0.405, 0.405, 0.405,0.405, 0.405, 0.405, 0.3664, 0.0627, 0.0534, 0.0534), deadTwig = c(0.9887,0.9887, 0.9887, 0.9887, 0.9887, 0.9887, 0.9537, 0.7391, 0.8132,0.8132), deadbole = c(2.3166, 2.3166, 2.3166, 2.3166, 2.3166,2.3166, 2.3947, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("row", "col", "cell","xcoord", "ycoord", "species", "age", "biomass", "stems", "slowGrowth","DBH", "height", "availableLight", "light_rf", "LeafArea", "nitorgen_rf","droughtIndex", "moisture_rf", "degreeDay_rf", "foliageWght","twigWght", "boleWght", "deadFoliage", "deadTwig", "deadbole"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 131023L, 131024L,131025L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
Details <- structure(list(fireID = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1052L,1052L, 1052L), decade = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 100L, 100L,100L), cell = c(14150L, 14321L, 14320L, 14489L, 14323L, 13977L,14492L, 14461L, 14122L, 14123L), row = c(128L, 129L, 129L, 130L,129L, 127L, 130L, 130L, 128L, 128L), column = c(137L, 137L, 136L,135L, 139L, 136L, 138L, 107L, 109L, 110L), biomass = c(0.724241,0.652821, 0.776811, 0.860563, 0.649643, 0.751143, 0.760428, 20.5968,33.6653, 15.1725)), .Names = c("fireID", "decade", "cell", "row","column", "biomass"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,12896L, 12897L, 12898L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to match these two dataset by rows and cols. Actually, I did it with

```
aa <- merge.data.frame(Details, output1, by=c("cell","row"))
```

but the problem is I have many rows in `output1` which has same coordinates. However I only want to get one coordinates for each row in my `details` output.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dim(output1)` is `10x25` , whereas after dropping duplicates for `row`, it gives a `3x25` dataframe. Are you sure this is what you want to work with? Just the three values, or should it be the combinations of unique `row` and `cell`?

Comment: I want to exclude rows which has same combinations of row and cells. Not only one of these. So if both rows and cells same then it should be excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you need something like this:

```
aa <- aa[!duplicated(aa[c("row", "cell")]), ]
```

I am removing not unique combinations of row and cell because I would imagine that cell plays a role in your analysis since you use it in the merge. Otherwise:

```
 aa <- aa[!duplicated(aa["row"]), ]
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Not answering your question after all?

Comment: No not really. I realised that (thanks to Aramis7d) this only check them one by one. I want to exclude rows which has same "rows" and "cell" or am I wrong? I'm testing it again now.

Comment: Nope sorry, it's true! :-)